# Cannot use @types/d3-tip: Argument of type 'Tooltip' is not assignable

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I am using @types/d3-tip with d3 as follows:

```
self.tooltip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'tooltip')
  .offset([-10,0])
  .html(function(d: Datapoint) {
    ...
  })

self.svg.call(self.tooltip)
```

This throws up an error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Tooltip' is not assignable to parameter of type '(sel: Selection<SVGElement>, ...args: any[]) => any'.
  Type 'Tooltip' provides no match for the signature '(sel: Selection<SVGElement>, ...args: any[]): any'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `as` keyword to overcome the type-checker error like this:

```
self.svg.call(self.tooltip as any)
```

This approach may be controversial based on [this discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9448) but it will allow you to overcome the error.

Comment: Yeah this is what I'm doing for now.